# TColumn.FieldName property editor

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, tcollection, tcollectionitem, tpersistent

I'm analyzing the `DBGrids.pas` unit. There's a `TColumn` class which have published the `FieldName` property

```
property  FieldName: String read FFieldName write SetFieldName;
```

It's declared as a string but in the object inspector it's appear as a editable combobox (`TDataFieldProperty`)

I analyzed almost all `DBGrids` unit and can't find place where that trick is done. Where should I look?

Comment: Look into the DBReg.pas unit.

Comment: I think it's done by the `RegisterPropertiesInCategory` in `DBReg.pas` as you wrote. Can you post an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I know almost nothing about IDE editors, so I can't confirm that or help you more about this. Let's do it someone more experienced.

Comment: For me it's more than enough :)

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for - dear past me - is the [RegisterPropertyEditor](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/DesignIntf.RegisterPropertyEditor) method.

> Call RegisterPropertyEditor to associate the property editor class
>   specified by the EditorClass parameter with the property type
>   specified by the PropertyType parameter.

In your case you need a TDataFieldProperty so it will be like:

```
RegisterPropertyEditor(TypeInfo(string), TColumn, 'FieldName', TDataFieldProperty);
```

Comment: Still can't find where 'FieldName' property editor is registered, though

Comment: what you mean by "where 'FieldName' property editor is registered?

Comment: @jachguate - AFAIU it means the answer does not answer the question.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question asks *where* the property editor is registered. This answer tells *what* the registration might look like, but there is no such line anywhere in the source code.

Comment: In Delphi 5 it is registered for TColumn on line 473 of the `dbreg` unit: `RegisterPropertyEditor(TypeInfo(string), TColumn, 'FieldName', TColumnDataFieldProperty);`

Comment: @Marjan - You've got it, it's in vcldbreg.pas in newer versions.

Comment: @MarjanVenema My delphi 7  `dbreg` it's only 411 lines long and it's not containig such line :(

Comment: Most probably it is in a different unit. Sertac has already given you a hint where it lives in newer versions. If it isn't there, use your favorite grep utility and look for all RegisterPropertyEditor lines until you find it... That's how I found it in D5.

Comment: @MarjanVenema I've greped all disc but I haven't found `TColumn` registering a property editor (and I've got only `TDataFieldProperty` but not `TColumnDataFieldProperty`) - it just bothering me so much

Comment: Well, that's unfortunate, but it has to be there somewhere or it wouldn't work. Though of course the IDE doesn't use the source directly. Do hope you didn't (inadvertently) change the vcl sources... I am sorry but I can't help you further, don't have D7 and can't look on your hard disk.

Comment: Just - The source is missing, also in D2007. That's why we failed to locate it. It was only after @Marjan mentioned TColumnDataFieldProperty I gave it another chance with other versions, f.i. XE and XE2 have it. There's not much you can do about it, the vendor will not fix it.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Yea you're right - I've greped it in dcldb.bpl file but can't find it in pas file. Thank you for clarifying :)